# Transformations in a Cox Model

Tags: regression, survival, data-transformation, cox-model

I am standardizing all my continuous covariates (and log transforming them to minimize undue influence). However I would like to express the change in the log hazard per 10 year change for my covariate "Age" because standard deviation will not make much sense for this particular variable. Is this an acceptable given it will be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Assuming that your age variable is measured in years (and is not discretized), then you can simply divide the  age variable by 10.  When you fit your model, the resulting hazard ratio will be interpreted as the multiplicative change in the baseline hazard per 10 year change in age.

Here is an example in R

```
library(survival)
data(ovarian)

model = coxph(Surv(futime,fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian)
summary(model)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian)

  n= 26, number of events= 12 

       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
age 0.16162   1.17541  0.04974 3.249  0.00116 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
age     1.175     0.8508     1.066     1.296

Concordance= 0.784  (se = 0.083 )
Likelihood ratio test= 14.29  on 1 df,   p=2e-04
Wald test            = 10.56  on 1 df,   p=0.001
Score (logrank) test = 12.26  on 1 df,   p=5e-04
```

Per 1 year change in age, the hazard is expected to increase by a factor of 1.17 (equivalently, the log-hazard ratio is 0.16).

Now, let's divide age by 10

```
ovarian$age = ovarian$age/10
model = coxph(Surv(futime,fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian)
summary(model)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian)

  n= 26, number of events= 12 

      coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
age 1.6162    5.0339   0.4974 3.249  0.00116 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
age     5.034     0.1987     1.899     13.34

Concordance= 0.784  (se = 0.083 )
Likelihood ratio test= 14.29  on 1 df,   p=2e-04
Wald test            = 10.56  on 1 df,   p=0.001
Score (logrank) test = 12.26  on 1 df,   p=5e-04
```

Note that the log hazard ratio has now changed.  It has increased by a factor of 10 (from 0.16 to 1.6).  This is because in the new age variable, an increase of 1 unit is equivalent to an increase in 10 units in the old age variable.

Also note that a scaling in the variable does not lead to an equivalent change in the hazard ratio but in the log-hazard ratio.  In our first model, the hazard ratio was 1.17, but in the new model it is ~5.0.